# Access Google Cloud Datastore Making a Apex callout in salesforce

Tags: web-services, salesforce, apex, google-cloud-datastore

How do I Access Google Cloud Datastore JSON API Making a Apex Call Out in   Sales force?

Please Help me?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This problem is solved now